# urllib urlopen throws 403 status code: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

I tried to test the connection to the website on PyCharm.
When I run the code I am faced with this error:

I use BeautifulSoup modules

```python
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_html(url):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    return response.read()

def parse(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

def main():
    print(get_html('https://tap.az/'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

```
C:\Users\Adil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe  C:/Users/Adil/Desktop/PAbot/pabot.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/Adil/Desktop/PAbot/pabot.py", line 21, in <module>
        main()
      File "C:/Users/Adil/Desktop/PAbot/pabot.py", line 17, in main
        print(get_html('https://tap.az/'))
      File "C:/Users/Adil/Desktop/PAbot/pabot.py", line 8, in get_html
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
      File "C:\Users\Adil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
        return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
      File "C:\Users\Adil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
        response = meth(req, response)
      File "C:\Users\Adil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_response
        'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
      File "C:\Users\Adil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 569, in error
        return self._call_chain(*args)
      File "C:\Users\Adil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
        result = func(*args)
      File "C:\Users\Adil\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
        raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Comment: You are getting 403 error. According to http status codes, the 403 Forbidden error is an HTTP status code that means that accessing the page or resource you were trying to reach is absolutely forbidden for some reason.

Comment: In other words, you should  not ask *us* why that page gives you 403. You should ask the site owner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a user agent in your request header.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0'
headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}
request = urllib.request.Request(url='https://tap.az/', headers=headers)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
result = BeautifulSoup(response.read(), 'html.parser')
print(result)
```

Comment: I don't know if this can work for all the websites but for your case my answer works fine.